# How to press button, hold and release on the other button

Tags: mouse, pywinauto

I need to click on one button A1, hold left mouse click and then move mouse, so that I can select for example first 5 fields (A1 to A5). I have table with columns from A to G and rows from 1 to 12. Each field is button, so I need function for selection certain number of the fields.

I tried here with hold and release, but that didn't work.

> window.child_window(auto_id="A1", control_type="Custom",
> found_index=0).hold(button='left')
>
> window.child_window(auto_id="A5", control_type="Custom",
> found_index=0).release(button='left')

I also tried with drag mouse input, but still doesn't work.

> A1 = window.child_window(auto_id="A1", control_type="Custom",
> found_index=0)
>
> A5 = window.child_window(auto_id="A5", control_type="Custom",
> found_index=0)
>
> window.DragMouseInput("left", A1.Rectangle().mid_point(),
> A5.Rectangle().mid_point())

SOLVED:

```
cell1 = window.child_window(auto_id=start_well, control_type="Custom")
cell2 = window.child_window(auto_id=end_well, control_type="Custom")

start_coords = cell2.rectangle().mid_point()
end_coords = cell1.rectangle().mid_point()

pyautogui.moveTo(start_coords[0], start_coords[1], duration=0.5)
pyautogui.mouseDown()

pyautogui.moveTo(end_coords[0], end_coords[1], duration=2)
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

Comment: tag pywinauto should be replaced by pyautogui